# Beginner problem with ASP.NET Web Service and IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services, iis

I am newbie in .NET. Now I am trying make my first ASP.NET Web Service.

I create ASP.NET Web Service Project and use default Web Methods generated by Visual Studio 2010.

I tested this service in Visual Studio, it works good.

Then I added virtual directory on IIS, directory name is test. I use Windows Server 2003 Standard.

And tried access to web service via localhost.

http://localhost/test/Service1.asmx

I got this error message:

```
The XML page cannot be displayed 
Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later. 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A name was started with an invalid character. Error processing resource 'http://localhost/w/Service1.asmx'. Line 1, Positi...
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="Service1.asmx.cs" Class="WebService1.Service1" %>
-^
```

I checked this files:

**Service1.asmx**

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="Service1.asmx.cs" Class="WebService1.Service1" %>
```

**Service1.asmx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace WebService1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Service1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }
}
```

What can be bad? Thank for support.

Comment: Check selected asp.net version on your `test` virtual directory, it would be `2.0.50727`.

Comment: It's not the answer to your question but I would consider using a WCF service instead of the classic asmx web service.

Comment: You should not use ASMX services for new development. Microsoft now considers them to be a "legacy technology". WCF should be used for all new service and client development.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like ASP.NET is not enabled on the IIS machine.

You might want to check your windows components `control panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off` and check if the `Internet Information Services/World Wide Web Services/Application Development Features/ASP.NET` feature is enabled on the machine running IIS and check to install it if it's not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

.Try running [aspnet regiis utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) command found in C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
 folder.Maybe script maps not updated correctly.If you already have IIS installed,Did you installed IIS after installing .NET framework?

> aspnet_regiis -i